Salty lasagna spill possibly killed laptop; is data recovery possible?
I was carrying my laptop in a bag with a lasagna which burst. A small amount of the liquid came into contact with the laptop. I didn't think it was enough to cause a problem, but it is salty.
I turned my computer on and it worked, but a few hours later I tried again and this time I was told it was doing a "BIOS recovery", the fans whirred loudly, and then the computer shutoff. It now refuses to turn on.
If given a power supply, the LED will just blink. It has dried and still does this.
Is it possible the data on the SSD is recoverable? What steps would you recommend?

You turned it on before it dried? Sounds like you should take it somewhere who can disassemble it and clean each part. It’s nearly impossible for us to guess what part failed based off the information provided

I was carrying my laptop in a bag with a lasagna... There's your problem.

Take it to a repair shop.

There is still a good chance for recovery. Depending on the laptop, the SSD may be removable and read externally, or it may be fully integrated and could require fixing the laptop. There are also sometimes security measures that prevent accessing the SSD's data when the rest of the laptop does not function (particularly with Apple and newer laptops), making recovery more difficult. But a knowledgeable computer repair person or data recovery service will know how to diagnose, replace components as needed, etc.

Most likely there is a short circuit on your motherboard caused by the liquid. I think the data can be very easily recovered, since the SSD is supposed to be fine, just either plug it into another computer if you have or go to a repair shop and ask them to export the data for you.
In rare cases, the liquid could destroy some of the capacitor or circuit on the board in a special way which will causes power surge and destroy your ssd completely (very unlikely). Depending on how expensive the laptop is, the best option might be repairing the motherboard instead of just simply recover the data.
